# responsive image inside svg

Tags: css, svg, media-queries, embedded-resource

TL;DR: Is it possible to load other images based on media-query from svg included via `img` tag?

I generate a bunch of svg files with have tables with text and icons inside. A PDF would be semantically a better container, but I need to keep such "documents" as images for seamless embed/preview and it probably won't solve my problem. So the story is about icons.

I wrote inline styles with media queries picking icons corresponding to user's screen DPI. Icons are already bundled into sprites, so I use `pattern/image[xlink:href]` + `fill:url(#id)`. Everything works as needed when I embed svg directly into HTML (DOM islands). But if I embed svg via `img` tag (i.e. `<img src="foo.svg">`), it doesn't load icons at all, let alone showing them.

I understand, that I can embed icons via data-URL, but embedding icons for all supported screen dpis seems too much. The irony is that icons are raster ones, hardly vectorizable pixel-art, so I cannot have one set of icons for all DPIs.

Is there a way to have proper icons picked by media query w/o embedding them all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't load external files from an SVG used in an `<img>` tag (or used in other "image" contexts, like CSS background images). For security and performance reasons, SVG used as image has to behave like any other image -- a single file, no secondary resources and no scripts.

If you don't want to use inline SVG, you might consider embedding an SVG file with an `<object>` tag or `<iframe>`.  However, I recommend that you actually test carefully to see whether browsers are downloading the image files even if they aren't using them because of CSS.

Comment: As I said, I have limitations on how it could be embedded. People would like to see those documents inline on a forum, where all one has for that is `[img]` BB-code. So neither `object` nor `embed` works in my case If they post link, they can post link to full document (which might also have hyperlinks in text).
It seems, though, that svg with embedded icons for retina is less than one-piece non-retina png.

Answer (score 0):

So since it's not possible to load conditionally: either embed or not, I should do some clever detection about raster sets. Technically not a direct answer, but in case someone needs.

I decided to go with cookies. People visit normally the same site that hosts those SVG.
I'd set a cookie for their DPI and then all SVGs served would pick proper DPI images.
For people who haven't visited the site yet, I'd go with UA sniffing: mobiles and macs get 2x, others 1x. Or just 1x for everyone.